# OpenGL flow camera in a stadium, how?

Tags: opengl

I have a scene, that is an arena (so basically this is a cube space) 
What is the best way to simulate a fly camera in this cube? 
(lets say the scene is an arena, or stadium with an origo point)

I have the gluLookat to change the camera view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean exactly?
If I understood you correctly, you could let the camera look at a fixed point (e.g. the center of the arena) and then using sin/cos trickery rotate the camera around it.

Comment: i d like some PRO camera movement, like in FIFA, so not a simple circle or ellipse/bezier, etc or something that...

Comment: Create something that lets you movely freely through the arena. Then find (manually) viewpoints that you like. Write those down and then later use regular linear/etc. movements between those points. It is really not a special trick. Als "Pro camera movement" is not a clear description of what you want. No idea what a fifa is.